# Test case is showing passed even if exception occurs in test scripts in testNG framework

Tags: selenium

Test cases result is showing passed if any type of exception occurs in between in my test script. Kindly tell me why its showing?

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button type="button" id="chqClrModalSubt" class="btn btn-primary">...</button> is not clickable at point (758, 236). Other element would receive the click: <div class="sweet-alert showSweetAlert visible" data-custom-class="" data-has-cancel-button="false" data-has-confirm-button="true" data-allow-outside-click="false" data-has-done-function="true" data-animation="pop" data-timer="null" style="display: block; margin-top: -117px;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'BINALI-094', ip: '192.168.70.21', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031..., userDataDir: C:\Users\AR-2104\AppData\Lo...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:53878}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 73.0.3683.103, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: f4c238094e8add745e7c4ba926c015c0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.click(Unknown Source)
    at pom.ReceiptVoucher.CheckRVfromDirectInvoice(ReceiptVoucher.java:310)
    at script.VerifyRVfrmDirectInvoice.testVerifyRVfrmDirectInvoice(VerifyRVfrmDirectInvoice.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
PASSED: testVerifyRVfrmDirectInvoice

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: What is the view point of the element ? is it visible in UI when selenium tries to interact with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below method for clicking any element in applications.

```
    public void click(){
    try{
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("button id"));

    if(element.isEnabled()){
    //Click on elemnet
    element.click();
    }else{
    //Web Element is not enabled in application
    }
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}


    }
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, My scenario is if  any exception occurs test script is failing. but in result its showing as passed.